# How do I import PHP array in a JSON array?

Tags: php, arrays, json

So I have a PHP script where I ask a simple query and then I put it in an array.

```
<?php
$query = mysql_query('SELECT ATX12V FROM results');
$resultSet = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
    $resultSet['ATX12V'] = $row['ATX12V'];
    $data[] = $resultSet;
}
print json_encode($data);
?>
```

The outcome of print json_encode($data) is:

[{"ATX12V":"10"},{"ATX12V":"65"},{"ATX12V":"64"},{"ATX12V":"96"}]

Below I have a javascript code and my question is how do I add $data to the data[]??

```
<script>
var buyerData = {
    labels : ["January","February","March","April","May","June", "July", "August"],
    datasets : [
    {
        fillColor : "#9DB86D",
        strokeColor : "#ACC26D",
        pointColor : "#9DB86D",
        pointStrokeColor : "#9DB86D",
        data : []
    }
    ]
}
</script>
```

Comment: at what point is the PHP executing? is it running during the page request, or is it during an AJAX request?

Comment: Is this script on the same page after the php code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about simple:

```
data : <?php echo json_encode($data); ?>
```

Comment: Omg that did work! I'm sorry, i'm new to JSON! Thank you very much!

Comment: @user3638258 If you find my answer helpful, remember to accept it with the thick on the left.

Answer (score 0):

you can use  ajax like :

(home.html):

```
<script type="text/javascript">


        window.onload = function() {

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "request.php",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {

                alert(data[0].ATX12V);                   

                }
            });
        }

</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
```

and server side (request.php) :

```
<?php
$query = mysql_query('SELECT ATX12V FROM results');
$resultSet = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
    $resultSet['ATX12V'] = $row['ATX12V'];
    $data[] = $resultSet;
}
print json_encode($data);
?>
```

note: Add jquery.js in your project